# How to store select option onchange in variable and pass it as argument in single php page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a specific requirement in php page. I am running 2 query which fetches shell script name from my mysql DB. 
1st query : executes and provide output in dropdown list which is working fine.
2nd query : If any option is selected from dropdown list, the value should pass as input argument to my 2nd shell script. This I am unable to achieve. 
Kindly guide me for same.

Below is my php page code:

```
<?php
include('db.php');

function connect_db (){
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect to database' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('dashboard');
}



function close(){
    mysql_close();
}



function query1(){
    connect_db ();
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM webpage WHERE page = 'display_peer_info.php' ");
    $record = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $script = $record['arg1_script'];

    $conn = ssh2_connect('$server_ip',$port);
    ssh2_auth_password($conn, '$user', '$pass');
    //Executing 1st shell script on remote server and saving output in a variable
    $script_output = ssh2_exec($conn, "/home/$user/bin/webscript/$script");

    stream_set_blocking($script_output, true);
    while($line = fgets($script_output)) {
        flush();
        echo '<option value='.$line.'>'. $line . '</option>';
    }

}

function query2(){
    connect_db ();
    $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM webpage WHERE page = 'display_peer_info.php' ");
    $record1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1);
    $script1 = $record1['page_script'];

    $conn = ssh2_connect('$server_ip',$port);
    ssh2_auth_password($conn, '$user', '$pass');

    //Getting value from dropdown list
    $dropdown_value = $_POST['arg1'];
    // Executing 2nd shell script on same remote server with Argument selected from dropdown list 
    $script_output1 = ssh2_exec($conn, "/home/oaa/bin/webscript/$script1 \"$dropdown_value\"  " );
    echo  $script_output1;
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="webpage">
    <select  id="arg1">
        <?php    query1();?>
    </select>
    <?php close(); ?>

</div><br />
<div id="output">
    <? php query2(); ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest some logic/workaround to get output from my 2nd query function.

Comment: You didn't explain what went wrong here. What errors did you get? What was the output that was expected versus the output you actually got? What steps did you take to debug or troubleshoot?

Comment: With above code: I get Resource id #9  as output. Actually I am not able to find a logic, how to pass dropdown list select option in my 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

## First and Foremost

You **absolutely should NOT** be using `mysql_query` or any of the old `ext/mysql` functions anymore. These functions have been deprecated for years and were removed from PHP 7.

If you've taken just one quick [look at the PHP manual](http://php.net/mysql-query) for any of these functions in the last ~4 years you'd see this big red warning at the top of every page that looks something like this.

> **Warning** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
> - [PDO::query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

---

The issues with the above code are quite numerous and broad. Since you haven't clearly described which specific problem you're trying to solve I'll just generally address the ones that stand out.

1. Arguments in your shell (like `$dropdown_value`) may need escaped ([see `escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg))
2. `ssh2_exec` returns a stream resource, not a string ([read the manual on how to use it](http://php.net/shell2-exec))
3. Functions should return values, not print directly to output

Your most critical issue is probably in using `shell2_exec`. You're clearly assuming it returns a string when in fact it returns a stream resource. You need to read from this stream resource using something like [`fread`](http://php.net/fread), for example.

```
$stream =  ssh2_exec($conn, "/home/oaa/bin/webscript/$script1 \"$dropdown_value\"  " );
$buffer = "";
while($data = fread($stream, 8192)) {
    $buffer .= $data;
}
fclose($stream);
echo $buffer; // this will be a string
```

Since you never explain what format the expected output from your shell script should be it's unclear how to help you further from here to process that output to your HTML.

Comment: Thanks Sherif for your valuable inputs & quick response. My 2nd query will output a proper string if I pass proper argument to it. My query is  e.g. <option>1</option>;<option>2</option>;<option>3</option> . If 2 is selected from dropdown list. I want this value to store in $dropdown_value variable. Can you suggest what logic I can use to achieve this result.

Comment: This seems to be a different question than the one you're asking here. StackOverflow comments are not designed to accommodate providing additional thread footprint for new questions. Merely followup discussion that should ultimately fold up into the designated answer. I would recommend that you post a new question if you have a new question.